# I want to achieve specific kind of lighting for my render but cant get there

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I've been trying to figure out a solution, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I almost got it to look the way I wanted, but it seems to lack natural lighting and such. I'm new to Blender so I don't know what I can do to make it look like it does in the reference.

That's what I did:

[image]

That is what I want to achieve:

[image]

These seem to look better, but I don't know how to achieve this kind of render or lighting.

Comment: it looks like you don't enough things to reflect in front of your object, maybe use an HDRI if you don't already, or change it for another one

Comment: thank you for helping and answering,i was using RGB instead of environment texture now that i added that it looks great,but only small issue the hdri reflects in the backgroud too.

Comment: So make the background non reflective, like a second plane that is not glossy

Comment: sorry it took some time to separate because it was kinda curved plane to cut and then change the material of the half plane but yeah did it somehow it removed the reflection but the pure black color is not coming back sorry for asking too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough things to reflect in front of your object, you could use lights like areas but an HDRI as background of your *World* is more interesting in terms of reflections. If you've enabled the addon called *Node Wrangler*, just select the *Background* node and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, it will automatically create a node chain with an *Environment Texture* node. You have websites like polyhaven or ambientCG that offer free HDRIs:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much again i really appreciate your time and effort and it really helped me out,again thank you it is finally done as i wanted to yeah i have just installed Node Wrangler and did what you instructed and it is done.